# Limit not working in many to many sequelize

Tags: pagination, sequelize.js, many-to-many, limit

Limit doesn't work as we want it to be. We have a project model, a tags model, and a many to many relationship between these two, all we want is to get the data on say limit = 10.

```
Project.findAndCountAll({
  include: {
    model: TagModel,
    as: 'tags',
    required: false,
  },
    distinct: true,
    subQuery: false,
    limit: 10
})
```

The data returned on their join is 74 rows, applied limit results to first 10 rows, but that is not the correct data. The returned proejcts in first 10 records are only first 5 projects, because of the many to many join, others have been discarded because of the limit of 10.

I do not want the limit to be applied to the end result after the join, which causes this issue. I want to have the limit of 10 applied to projects only and then the join should happen with the tags and all tags of those 10 projects should be returned no matter how many they are (tags can be greater than 10 as well).

I have tried to put limit in the include as follows

```
Project.findAndCountAll({
  include: {
    model: TagModel,
    as: 'tags',
    required: false,
    limit: 10,
    separate: true
  },
    distinct: true,
    subQuery: false,
})
```

but it gives error

> "Only HasMany associations support include.separate

which seems to mean that, inside include we cannot apply limit in many to many relationship?

Comment: please share model

Answer (score 0):

Model: A.js

```js
"use strict";
const {
    Model
} = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class A extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            this.belongsTo(models.B, {
                foreignKey: "bId",
                as: "B",
            });
            this.belongsTo(models.C, {
                foreignKey: "cId",
                as: "C",
            });

        }
    }
    A.init({
        bId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        cId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "A",
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'A'
    });
    return A;
};
```

Model: B.js

```js
"use strict";
const {
    Model
} = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class B extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            this.hasMany(models.A, { // This is must: hasMany
                foreignKey: "bId",
                as: "A",
            });
        }
    }
    B.init({
        orgId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        contentId: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "B",
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'B'
    });
    return B;
};
```

```js
        var B = await db.B.findAll({
            limit: 2,
            include: [{
                model: db.A,
                as: 'A',
                required: false,
                limit: 2,
            }
            ]
        });

        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(B)));
```

Output

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    orgId: 101,
    contentId: 'content1',
    A: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    orgId: 101,
    contentId: 'content1',
    A: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```